Qualify class name in dart
How do I qualify a class name in dart? I've got the following code:

import '../../grpc_channel/Protos/Compiled/Common/Messages/Types.pb.dart';
import '../../grpc_channel/Protos/Compiled/SensorTypeDetection/Messages/SensorType.pb.dart';
import '../../grpc_channel/SensorTypeDetectionService.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});
  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => new _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  bool grpcConnectedState = false;
  String sensorType = "...";
  String serverAddress = "127.0.0.1";
  int serverPort = 5000;
  // .....
}

Types.pb.dart is generated from the following GRPC proto snippet:
message String
{
    string value = 1;
}

and thus contains an user defined type class String.
Now dart complains that String in String sensorType = "..."; is ambiguous. As a C# developer, I would just write System.String to make it clear that I mean the pre-defined type, but that doesn't work in dart. How do I resolve the ambiguity?
